# Is Vue.js component's vm.$el constant or can it be reassigned?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Vue.js component instances have a [`vm.$em` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el) that gives access to a component's root DOM element. Does the **value** of this property ever change during the lifecycle of a component or is it constant after the component is mounted? In other words, once a component's root DOM element is created, can it be replaced by Vue under some condition?

*I know the contents of the DOM element can of course change.*

According to a component's lifecycle diagram below, when data changes there is a "Virtual DOM re-render and patch." I read the doc and tried to find the answer in Vue's source, but I haven't found any conclusive answer so far.

The closest I've been with the source code is this in `src/core/instance/lifecycle.js`:

```
Vue.prototype._update = function (vnode: VNode, hydrating?: boolean) {
  const vm: Component = this
  const prevEl = vm.$el
  const prevVnode = vm._vnode
  const restoreActiveInstance = setActiveInstance(vm)
  vm._vnode = vnode
  // Vue.prototype.__patch__ is injected in entry points
  // based on the rendering backend used.
  if (!prevVnode) {
    // initial render
    vm.$el = vm.__patch__(vm.$el, vnode, hydrating, false /* removeOnly */)
  } else {
    // updates
    vm.$el = vm.__patch__(prevVnode, vnode)
  }
  restoreActiveInstance()
  // update __vue__ reference
  if (prevEl) {
    prevEl.__vue__ = null
  }
  if (vm.$el) {
    vm.$el.__vue__ = vm
  }
  // etc.
}
```

This suggests that `vm.$el` could be reassigned on every component render, but I haven't deciphered how `__patch__()` works so far to be sure and when `_update()` is called exactly.

#### Why bother?

I have some setup task to do on the root DOM element directly (e.g. setup a jQuery plugin). Is it enough to do this only in the `mounted` hook (yes if `vm.$el` is constant) or must I also do it in the `updated` hook when a change of `vm.$el` is detected?

[image: Vue.js lifecycle diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in complete control of the component content then you are *probably* save to assume that `vm.$el` won't change.  If you are making (for example) a mixin or directive then you can't - it is perfectly possible to make a component where the top level element can change by using the [is](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is) directive.

For example, this defines a component which can change it's top level element type:

```
Vue.component('comp',{
  props:{type:String},
  template:`
    <component :is="type">
       I am a {{type}}
    </component>
  `
})
```

This is a fiddle which demonstrates it: https://jsfiddle.net/tazfLqbh/1/

As good practice I would suggest assuming that it could change, as the behaviour does not seem to be defined formally in the documentation so behaviour can change with future versions.

#### Analysis of the fiddle

The question remains whether the dynamic component in the fiddle triggers the creation of a new Vue component when its type is toggled. In the dev console:

```
// "Inspect" the span
> a = $0.__vue__
VueComponent {_uid: 1, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}
// Toggle the type to div and "inspect" the div
> b = $0.__vue__
VueComponent {_uid: 1, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}
> a === b
true
```

So no new Vue component instance is created on toggle of the root element type.

As expected, this [fiddle shows](https://jsfiddle.net/8L6apwor/) that a dynamic *component type* does however trigger the creation of a new Vue component instance. In that case, it thus appears the `mounted` hook is enough. Something like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggle">
    Toggle div or span element
  </button>
  <component :is="span?'comp-span':'comp-div'"></component>
</div>

Vue.component('comp-span',{
  template:`
    <span>
       I am a span
    </span>
  `
})

Vue.component('comp-div',{
  template:`
    <div>
       I am a div
    </div>
  `
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I'll edit your answer with some additional info I got.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.

Comment: This also means that many tutorials on how to add a jQuery plugin to a Vue component are wrong. Those I read only say to hook the `mounted` stage. In fact, event the official Select2 example in the doc has it wrong then... https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html

Comment: Well, they are *mostly* right, as few developers do things like this at the top level of a component. Useful extra info BTW.  I had assumed that this was the case, but hadn't thought to test it.

Comment: Interesting discussion. I'd just like to point out, while the VueComponent does not change (in **Analysis of fiddle**), it's `$el` property does change (which is what Bernie is asking), but also should be aware that `$el` ***is*** the DOM element, so ***'I know the contents of the DOM element can of course change'*** answers the question already.

Comment: Also like to point out, in the second example `<component>` is not a VueComponent, so you could not define a `mounted()` hook for it (therefore the jquery problem does not really apply).